Model not working for Multiclass Segmentation
I am training a model for multiclass segmentation problem. I have 3 classes with image size of 512x512 and 1 channel. My dataset has imbalanced classes. The issue is that the model is not performing well for the multiclass segmentation.
I have tried with Cross Entropy Loss, Dice Loss, Jaccard Loss, and combination of Losses (Jaccard + Focal).
Cross Entropy is working fine but results are not satisfactory.
What changes should I made in it?
Below is the code of the model
class AxialDW(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim, mixer_kernel, dilation=1):
        super().__init__()
        h, w = mixer_kernel
        self.dw_h = nn.Conv2d(dim, dim, kernel_size=(h, 1), padding=(max(h // 2, dilation), 0), groups=dim, dilation=dilation)
        self.dw_w = nn.Conv2d(dim, dim, kernel_size=(1, w), padding=(0, max(w // 2, dilation)), groups=dim, dilation=dilation)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x + self.dw_h(x) + self.dw_w(x)
        return x


class EncoderBlock(nn.Module):
    """Encoding then downsampling"""

    def __init__(self, in_c, out_c, mixer_kernel=(7, 7)):
        super().__init__()
        self.dw = AxialDW(in_c, mixer_kernel=(7, 7))
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(in_c)
        self.pw = nn.Conv2d(in_c, out_c, kernel_size=1)
        self.down = nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2))
        self.act = nn.GELU()

    def forward(self, x):
        skip = self.bn(self.dw(x))
        x = self.act(self.down(self.pw(skip)))
        return x, skip


class DecoderBlock(nn.Module):
    """Upsampling then decoding"""

    def __init__(self, in_c, out_c, mixer_kernel=(7, 7)):
        super().__init__()
        self.up = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2)
        self.pw = nn.Conv2d(in_c + out_c, out_c, kernel_size=1)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_c)
        self.dw = AxialDW(out_c, mixer_kernel=(7, 7))
        self.act = nn.GELU()
        self.pw2 = nn.Conv2d(out_c, out_c, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x, skip):
        x = self.up(x)
        x = torch.cat([x, skip], dim=1)
        x = self.act(self.pw2(self.dw(self.bn(self.pw(x)))))
        return x


class BottleNeckBlock(nn.Module):
    """Axial dilated DW convolution"""

    def __init__(self, dim):
        super().__init__()

        gc = dim // 4
        self.pw1 = nn.Conv2d(dim, gc, kernel_size=1)
        self.dw1 = AxialDW(gc, mixer_kernel=(3, 3), dilation=1)
        self.dw2 = AxialDW(gc, mixer_kernel=(3, 3), dilation=2)
        self.dw3 = AxialDW(gc, mixer_kernel=(3, 3), dilation=3)

        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(4 * gc)
        self.pw2 = nn.Conv2d(4 * gc, dim, kernel_size=1)
        self.act = nn.GELU()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pw1(x)
        x = torch.cat([x, self.dw1(x), self.dw2(x), self.dw3(x)], 1)
        x = self.act(self.pw2(self.bn(x)))
        return x


class ULite(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, freeze_model, num_classes=3):
        super().__init__()

        """Encoder"""
        self.conv_in = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=7, padding=3)
        self.e1 = EncoderBlock(16, 32)
        self.e2 = EncoderBlock(32, 64)
        self.e3 = EncoderBlock(64, 128)
        self.e4 = EncoderBlock(128, 256)
        self.e5 = EncoderBlock(256, 512)

        """Bottle Neck"""
        self.b5 = BottleNeckBlock(512)

        """Decoder"""
        self.d5 = DecoderBlock(512, 256)
        self.d4 = DecoderBlock(256, 128)
        self.d3 = DecoderBlock(128, 64)
        self.d2 = DecoderBlock(64, 32)
        self.d1 = DecoderBlock(32, 16)
        self.conv_out = nn.Conv2d(16, num_classes, kernel_size=1)

        if freeze_model:
            self.freeze_model()

    def forward(self, x):
        """Encoder"""
        x = self.conv_in(x)
        x, skip1 = self.e1(x)
        x, skip2 = self.e2(x)
        x, skip3 = self.e3(x)
        x, skip4 = self.e4(x)
        x, skip5 = self.e5(x)

        """BottleNeck"""
        x = self.b5(x)  # (512, 8, 8)

        """Decoder"""
        x = self.d5(x, skip5)
        x = self.d4(x, skip4)
        x = self.d3(x, skip3)
        x = self.d2(x, skip2)
        x = self.d1(x, skip1)
        x = self.conv_out(x)

                # Apply softmax for multi-class classification
        x = F.softmax(x, dim=1)
        return x

    def freeze_model(self):
        for name, param in self.named_parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False

Jaccard + Focal Loss
Loss Image
Jaccard Loss
Loss Image
